# Using S3 Cloud Storage on IBM Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage

I am planning to use S3 Cloudstorage in IBM Bluemix but then one strange thing I found is that there is no way to add the custom META-DATA to the objects which are stored in S3 bucket.

Is there a way I can add custom Meta-Data to the objects and if yes then can you please advise on how we can add it and access it.?

Comment: Just checking - did you get this working properly?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for pointing out a hole in the documentation!

Custom metadata is defined by passing a `x-amz-meta-{key}` header with a `{value}` value.  As an example request:

```
PUT /{bucket-name}/{object-name} HTTP/1.1
Authorization: {authorization-string}
x-amz-meta-foo: bar
x-amz-date: 20160825T183001Z
x-amz-content-sha256:{hashed-body}
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Host: s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net
Content-Length: 18

{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

A HEAD request to check the metadata would look like:

```
HEAD /{bucket-name}/{object-name} HTTP/1.1
Authorization: {authorization-string}
x-amz-date: 20160825T183244Z
Host: s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net
```

And respond with:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 25 Aug 2016 18:32:44 GMT
X-Clv-Request-Id: da214d69-1999-4461-a130-81ba33c484a6
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: Cleversafe/3.9.1.102
X-Clv-S3-Version: 2.5
ETag: {MD5-hash}
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
x-amz-meta-foo: bar
Last-Modified: Thu, 25 Aug 2016 17:49:06 GMT
Content-Length: 18
```

Using the CLI, the syntax would be:

```
$ aws --endpoint-url=https://{endpoint} s3 cp ~/new-file s3://bucket-1/ --metadata foo=bar
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. I am using this every day . Adding meta data then sending the meta data in database by doing cron calls. 
Here is a small example of python script to create/add/change metadata for a a list object :

```
import sys
import os 
import boto3
import pprint
from boto3 import client
from botocore.utils import fix_s3_host

param_1= YOUR_ACCESS_KEY
param_2= YOUR_SECRETE_KEY
param_3= YOUR_END_POINT 
param_4= YOUR_BUCKET

#Create the S3 client
s3ressource = client(
    service_name='s3', 
    endpoint_url= param_3,
    aws_access_key_id= param_1,
    aws_secret_access_key=param_2,
    use_ssl=True,
    )
# Building a list  of object per bucket
def BuildObjectListPerBucket (variablebucket):
    global listofObjectstobeanalyzed
    listofObjectstobeanalyzed = []
    extensions = ['.jpg','.png']
    for key  in s3ressource.list_objects(Bucket=variablebucket)["Contents"]:
        #print (key ['Key'])
        onemoreObject=key['Key']
        if onemoreObject.endswith(tuple(extensions)):
            listofObjectstobeanalyzed.append(onemoreObject)

        else :
            s3ressource.delete_object(Bucket=variablebucket,Key=onemoreObject)          
    return listofObjectstobeanalyzed

# for a given existing object, create metadata
def createmetdata(bucketname,objectname):
    s3ressource.upload_file(objectname, bucketname, objectname, ExtraArgs={"Metadata": {"metadata1":"ImageName","metadata2":"ImagePROPERTIES" ,"metadata3":"ImageCREATIONDATE"}})

# for a given existing object, add new metadata
def ADDmetadata(bucketname,objectname):
    s3_object = s3ressource.get_object(Bucket=bucketname, Key=objectname)
    k = s3ressource.head_object(Bucket = bucketname, Key = objectname)
    m = k["Metadata"]
    m["new_metadata"] = "ImageNEWMETADATA"
    s3ressource.copy_object(Bucket = bucketname, Key = objectname, CopySource = bucketname + '/' + objectname, Metadata = m, MetadataDirective='REPLACE')

# for a given existing object, update  a metadata with new value
def CHANGEmetadata(bucketname,objectname):
    s3_object = s3ressource.get_object(Bucket=bucketname, Key=objectname)
    k = s3ressource.head_object(Bucket = bucketname, Key = objectname)
    m = k["Metadata"]
    m.update({'watson_visual_rec_dic':'ImageCREATIONDATEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE'})
    s3ressource.copy_object(Bucket = bucketname, Key = objectname, CopySource = bucketname + '/' + objectname, Metadata = m, MetadataDirective='REPLACE')

def readmetadata (bucketname,objectname):
    ALLDATAOFOBJECT = s3ressource.get_object(Bucket=bucketname, Key=objectname)
    ALLDATAOFOBJECTMETADATA=ALLDATAOFOBJECT['Metadata']
    print ALLDATAOFOBJECTMETADATA



# create the list of object on a per bucket basis

BuildObjectListPerBucket (variablebucket)

# Call functions to see the results 

for objectitem in listofObjectstobeanalyzed:
    readmetadata(param_4,objectitem)
    createmetdata(param_4,objectitem)
    readmetadata(param_4,objectitem)
    ADDmetadata(param_4,objectitem)
    readmetadata(param_4,objectitem)
    CHANGEmetadata(param_4,objectitem)
    readmetadata(param_4,objectitem)
```